# Does Type:Type lead to inconsistency without general inductive types?

Tags: type-theory, dependent-types, inductive-datatypes, agda

In e.g. Agda , it is possible to derive an element of the empty type by enabling the "type in type" option.

Every proof I have seen (and come up with) involves making a special inductive type definition.
Can a contradiction be derived using type in type but with e.g. only using standard library types?

Comment: Yes. See file [Hurkens.agda](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/e79cc2cbd85e81adc85dd4255851f53f9a838921/test/Succeed/Hurkens.agda) in the Agda repository.